# How to display new marker on the Leaflet map, after it has been inserted in the database?

Tags: leaflet, dynamically-generated

Nowadays all my geopoints are loaded on the page´s onload event.
I´d like to display new markers in the map, as soon as they come to the database.
Is there a way to notify leaflet when the inserts occur in the database ? Or something like that?
Or do i have to create a javascript infinit loop and keep this loop making ajax calls to check new positions at DB?

Comment: no easy task, but this may help you understand the issues - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743346/live-update-notification-on-database-changes-mysql-php

Comment: Im sorry, maybe i used the wrong words. It doesn´t need to be notified by the DB. I just need update the Map when a new position arrives. But i think im gonna do an infinite loop in the javascript, and keep checking on DB in every iteration.

Comment: better than an infinite loop - use a [polling strategy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583203/server-polling-with-javascript)