# Is it possible to refresh a Google map immediately?

Tags: mysql, google-maps, refresh

I can pull this information from my MySQL table and display what I need to but I would like some help on how to refresh this data every 5 seconds or so with the current code that I have.

There isn't much data to show, just like 5 or 8 markers at any given time. I have included my current code that I use to pull the data. I am sort of OK with PHP/MySQL but very new to Google Maps.
i try to add the code as  to refresh the google map

```
 setInterval(function() {
$.ajax({ url: '/localhost/my/site.php',
 data: {action: 'test'},
 type: 'post',
  success: function(output) {
      alert('hi');
     // change the DOM with your new output info
  }
});
}, 5000);
```

but still can't .what's wrong with my code ?
Is it possible to get new data from mysql when mysql database have update ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?  sensor=true" /></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
//This javascript will load when the page loads.
jQuery(document).ready( function($){
setInterval(function() {
  $.ajax({ url: '/localhost/my/site.php',
 data: {action: 'test'},
 type: 'post',
  success: function(output) {
      alert('hi');
     // change the DOM with your new output info
  }
 });
   }, 5000); 

    //Initialize the Google Maps
    var geocoder;
    var map;
    var markersArray = [];
    var infos = [];

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var myOptions = {
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
    //Load the Map into the map_canvas div
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    //Initialize a variable that the auto-size the map to whatever you are plotting
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    //Initialize the encoded string       
    var encodedString;

    //Initialize the array that will hold the contents of the split string
    var stringArray = [];

    //Get the value of the encoded string from the hidden input
    encodedString = document.getElementById("encodedString").value;

    //Split the encoded string into an array the separates each location
    stringArray = encodedString.split("****");

    var x;
 for (x = 0; x < stringArray.length; x = x + 1)
    {
        var addressDetails = [];
        var marker;
        //Separate each field
        addressDetails = stringArray[x].split("&&&");
        //Load the lat, long data
        var lat = new google.maps.LatLng(addressDetails[1], addressDetails[2]);
        var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(addressDetails[3]);

        //Create a new marker and info window
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            position: lat,
            content: addressDetails[0]
        });



        //Pushing the markers into an array so that it's easier to manage them
        markersArray.push(marker);
        google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function () {
            closeInfos();
            var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: this.content});
            //On click the map will load the info window
            info.open(map,this);
            infos[0]=info;
        });




       //Extends the boundaries of the map to include this new location
       bounds.extend(lat);
    }
    //Takes all the lat, longs in the bounds variable and autosizes the map
    map.fitBounds(bounds);



    //Manages the info windows
    function closeInfos(){
   if(infos.length > 0){
      infos[0].set("marker",null);
      infos[0].close();
      infos.length = 0;
   }
    }

});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id='input'>

<?php


//Initialize your first couple variables
$encodedString = ""; //This is the string that will hold all your location data
$x = 0; //This is a trigger to keep the string tidy

//Now we do a simple query to the database

// DB  INFO CONNECTION IS HERE AND WORKS

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ulocation` WHERE `ul_lat`!='' AND `ul_long`!=''  
AND `ul_onduty`='1'",$db1);

//Multiple rows are returned
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
{
    //This is to keep an empty first or last line from forming, when the string is 
split
    if ( $x == 0 )
    {
         $separator = "";
    }
    else
    {
         //Each row in the database is separated in the string by four *'s
         $separator = "****";
    }
    $status='0';
    $cadd  = sql::getval('cal_address', 'call', "WHERE    `cal_id`='$row[14]'");
    $num  = sql::getval('cal_num', 'call', "WHERE `cal_id`='$row[14]'");
    $pcond  = sql::getval('cal_pcond', 'call', "WHERE `cal_id`='$row[14]'");
    $list="$num $cadd";
    //Saving to the String, each variable is separated by three &'s
$encodedString = $encodedString.$separator."<table border=0 width='350' height='20'    
class='maincolm' cellpadding=0   cellspacing=0><td align=left valign=top><h2></h2></td>  
<tr><td width=100%><font size=3  face=arial><p><b>".$row[2].
        "</b>".
        "<br>Address: $list".
        "<br>Call Type: $pcond".
        "<br><br>Lat: ".$row[5].
        "<br>Long: ".$row[6].
        "</td></table>".
        "</p>&&&".$row[5]."&&&".$row[6]."&&&".$row[8]."&&&".$row[14];
       $x = $x + 1;
    }        
   ?>
<input type="hidden" id="encodedString" name="encodedString" value="<?php echo   
$encodedString; ?>" />
 <? echo "<body oncontextmenu=\"return false\" style=\"overflow: hidden; \"   
topmargin=0 leftmargin=0 rightmargin=0 bottommargin=0>";
  <div id=\"map_canvas\"></div>
  </body>
  </html>";
 ?>
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to links in here

[Live update notification on database changes MYSQL PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743346/live-update-notification-on-database-changes-mysql-php)

[How can I view live MySQL queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568564/how-can-i-view-live-mysql-queries)

What my conclusion is suggest to use polling, which make database call every X second to update the markers info.

Also, 1 of the post mentioned using trigger in mysql, you can also have a look at that.

Given that mysql don't notification

As a suggestion to your purpose. If you want refresh data from marker, for example, marker onclick event, from there you can make db call to refresh your marker. Thats how I would do it for marker onclick for instant

Hope it helps

Comment: can you give me some example about how to use polling which make database call every X second to update the markers info and marker color .

Comment: for marker info can use onclick event,but for marker option (for example :color),when specific table update ,the marker color will be from green to red

Comment: I would try this for polling.  Put a timer in your code, which makes db call to retrieve the data for each marker every X second or min.  also, in java you will need to store these markers in array, updates markers' option accordingly.

Comment: i have modify my post and add my code, do you have any suggestion , any help will be appreciated